# java.lang.VerifyError when running Android jUnit Test

Tags: android, junit

I've been trying to work out why I keep getting a `java.lang.VerifyError`
every time I try to instantiate one of my classes in any of my jUnit tests, but am completely stumped.

I created a simple, minimal test case that exhibits this behaviour:

```
package com.example;

public class Foo {

    private int bar;

    public Foo(int b) {
        bar = b;
    }

    public int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

}
```

And the unit tests:

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.example.Foo;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class FooTest extends TestCase {

    private Foo foo;

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    public void testSanity() {
        foo = new Foo(1);
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

When the unit tests attempts to instantiate a Foo object e.g. the first line of the `testSanity` method, I get a `java.lang.VerifyError`.

The project is being built against Android 1.6. The stack trace from DDMS in Eclipse looks like this:

```
05-16 23:40:01.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934): java.lang.VerifyError: com.example.tests.FooTest
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Native Method)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:484)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at junit.framework.TestSuite.getTestConstructor(TestSuite.java:177)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:59)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.getTest(BaseTestRunner.java:103)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.getTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:124)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.setTestClassName(AndroidTestRunner.java:52)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTestClassByName(TestSuiteBuilder.java:81)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClass(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:375)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClasses(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:357)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:325)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3848)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:116)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
05-16 23:40:01.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(934):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Met
```

Any help in fixing this and getting the tests running would be much appreciated.

### UPDATE

Further to [fadden's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294248/fadden) answer, the VFY logcat output is as follows:

```
05-18 20:33:04.052: ERROR/dalvikvm(234): Could not find class 'com.example.Foo', referenced from method com.example.tests.FooTest.testSanity
05-18 20:33:04.052: WARN/dalvikvm(234): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 5 (Lcom/example/Foo;) in Lcom/example/tests/FooTest;
05-18 20:33:04.052: WARN/dalvikvm(234): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x22 at 0x0001
05-18 20:33:04.052: WARN/dalvikvm(234): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/tests/FooTest;.testSanity ()V
05-18 20:33:04.052: WARN/dalvikvm(234): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/tests/FooTest;
```

Comment: Your test case is valid. Probably you removed something that's causing the error.

Answer (score 3):

The verifier in 1.5/1.6 was pretty severe.  The detailed explanation of the problem is on the lines above the exception (look for "VFY" in the logcat output).

**UPDATE:** looking at the logcat output, code in com.example.tests.FooTest is not able to find com.example.Foo.  In Android >= 2.0 this would result in a ClassNotFoundException, but in 1.6 the verifier gets cranky and just rejects the whole class.

So the question is: why can't it find it?  The first thing I'd check is to make sure both com.example.Foo and com.example.tests.FooTest appear in the same APK / classes.dex file.  You can check this by examining them with "dexdump".

Comment: +1 - I'm getting ERROR/dalvikvm(234): Could not find class 'com.example.Foo', referenced from method com.example.tests.FooTest.testSanity in the logcat output (I've updated my question to reflect this) - still no nearer getting the tests to run though

Comment: Updated the answer.  When in doubt, dump the DEX file. :-)